# JQuery Form success callback not being called

Tags: jquery

I have searched and can't find an answer that matches my exact situation so first off, apologies if this is a duplicate.

I am using ASP.Net MVC 3, and am submitting a form using the JQuery form plugin.  The form submits correctly and I am able to step through the code behind etc however the success callback is never called - I've stripped back my code to as simple as possible:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    BindForm();
});

function BindForm() {
    $('#PaydayForm').ajaxForm({
        error:  function() { alert("Error");},
        success: function() { alert("Success");},
    });
}
```

The form submits but neither error or success is called!

Comment: what html returns from your script where you posting data?

Comment: @ARTstudio - the output is an ASP.net MVC partial, just a form.  The Javascript is in the containing view not the partial.  I have removed the target from here for testing however it works correctly in terms of replacing the form content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel a little foolish however posting the answer in case anybody comes across this - the success callback WAS being called, it was the alert box that was being suppressed by Firefox.  I do not know why and have not looked too far into this however when I changed the alert to a simple function changing some text within a div it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you submitting cross-domain with ajax? That's one reason I can think where you will receive the data on the server but your JavaScript code will either not receive a success callback at all (Firefox) or will get the call but never the response data (Chrome).